# How to correctly align and position using GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to align my components like the following:

[image]

But at the moment they're like this: 
[image]

The two components are on a JPanel using `FlowLayout` (constructor contains `FlowLayout.LEFT`). The first component has these grid bag constraints:

```
GridBagConstraints windowTitleLabelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
windowTitleLabelConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
windowTitleLabelConstraints.gridx = 0;
windowTitleLabelConstraints.gridy = 0;
```

And these are the constraints for the second component:

```
GridBagConstraints column1Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
column1Constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
column1Constraints.gridx = 0;
column1Constraints.gridy = 1;
```

I've tried setting the `gridy` for the second component to `GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE` but there was no change.

I would also like for this to be possible:

[image]

Comment: `GridBagConstraints` should be used with `GridBagLayout`. Not `FlowLayout`. See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html): "The GridBagConstraints class specifies constraints for components that are laid out using the GridBagLayout class."

Comment: You don't need to keep creating a new GridBagConstraint. So you can set some default values and then just make simple changes for each component. For example, only the gridy, will be different for the two components. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Start with the working code and modify it to display your two components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working code for your case with 3 boxes;

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize( 800, 300 );

        JPanel screen = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        screen.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground( Color.RED );
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        screen.add( panel1, gbc );

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel2.setBackground( Color.ORANGE );
        screen.add( panel2, gbc );

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        screen.add( panel3, gbc );

        frame.add( screen );
        frame.setVisible( true );
```

[image]